# how to scrape telegram members about/bio information

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I tried this code to scrape telegram's username, userids. I need to scrape user's about/bio info too but after trying many codes from telethon, pyrogram etc, it didnt't worked. I recently started learning python basics. I have mentioned below the code i have tried, but it didn't work. I am looking for scraping only userid, username and specially /about/bio info of group members.

Tried this code
https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1243#issue-472897491

I did tried it by using below code but in out i am getting  "function get_user_bio at 0x7f xxxxxxxxx" in place of bio in output, rest all details are coming perfectly, its just the bio information which is not correct.

```py
from telethon.tl.functions.users
import GetFullUserRequest

async def get_user_bio(client, user):
    try:
    full_user = await client(GetFullUserRequest(user))
return full_user.full_user.about
except ChatAdminRequiredError:

# Get the user's bio
bio = full_user.full_user.about
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using, you'll need [`GetFullUserRequest`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/examples/users.html?highlight=GetFullUserRequest#id2) to get the complete user.

The pitfall here is that [`GetFullUserRequest`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/examples/users.html?highlight=GetFullUserRequest#id2) returns an object with the `full_user` attribute, so you'll need something like `fullUser.full_user.about` to get the Bio.

---

Consider this example were we

1. Loop over each dialog we have [`iter_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/quick-references/client-reference.html?highlight=iter_dialogs#dialogs)
2. Loop over each member of this dialog [`iter_participants`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.iter_participants)
3. (Remember this in the `seenUsers` list so we're not going to call `GetFullUserRequest` for user's we've already checked)
4. Get the complete user [`GetFullUserRequest`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/examples/users.html?highlight=GetFullUserRequest#id2)
5. Log `about` if it's set and not `None`

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest

import asyncio

async def main():

    seenUsers = []

    async with TelegramClient('anon', '111', '22') as client:

        # For each dialog
        async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs(limit = None):

            # For each particiipant
            async for user in client.iter_participants(entity=dialog, limit=None, aggressive=True):

                # Prevent double
                if user.first_name in seenUsers:
                    continue
                seenUsers.append(user.first_name)

                # Get full user
                fullUser = await client(GetFullUserRequest(user))

                # Log description
                if fullUser.full_user.about:

                    # Log
                    print(user.first_name + " has the following Bio:")
                    print(fullUser.full_user.about)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This will output something like:

```
Dirk has the following Bio:
Hi I'm Dirk

...
```